# Regex to check to string containing whitespace & special chars

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex statement:

```
String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,12})";
```

And I check the statement like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password); 
if(!matcher.matches()) {
  // error
}
```

How can I adjust this pattern to include checking for any whitespace and special characters? As in the matches() method should fail if the password contains any whitespace or any special characters.

Comment: use \\s  for matching white space

Comment: Can you give sample input, and what you want the regex to match?

Comment: Can you define special characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to reject whitespaces, you can use:

```
(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\\S{6,12}
```

`\\S` will match only non-whitespaces.

Also, you probably don't need the outer parentheses.

EDIT: Didn't see the other parts.

If you want to reject special characters, you can change the `\\S` to a negated class. Using this though would mean you'll have to use: `[^\\s ... ]`

For example, let's say there shouldn't be any `?` or whitespace. This becomes:

```
(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^\\s?]{6,12}
```

If you don't want `!` either:

```
(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^\\s?!]{6,12}
```

Comment: I really like your approach. It is cleaner, sorter and most probably faster ten suggested in my answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

> As in the matches() method should fail if the password contains any whitespace or any special characters

Just like you are using look-ahead `(?=....)` to check if password contains at least one

- digit `(?=.*\\d)`,
- lower-case letter `(?=.*[a-z])`
- upper-case letter `(?=.*[A-Z])`

you can add negative-look-ahead `(?!...)` to make sure that your password will not contain any unwanted characters like

- whitespace `(?!.*\\s)`
- special characters (depending on what you want here), for example can't have `+`, `-`, `!` `(?!.*[+\\-!])`

Now just combine all of it in one pattern

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\\s)(?!.*[+\\-!]).{6,12})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
[\w/^\s]
```

- **\w** detects the use of word characters (no special characters). 
- **^** means NOT and **\s** is used to detect a white space character. 
- Thus, **^\s** ensures there is no white space.

Full string:

```
"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\w)(?=.*[\w/^\s])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,12})"
```